# Windows Server 2003- RDP functionality after removing Terminal Server temporary CALs

Tags: windows-server-2003, rdp, terminal-server

I recently configured Windows Server 2003 Terminal Services for a client. The 90 day trial CAL period is about to expire, and my client has decided that he's too cheap to purchase CALs. He wants to use the 2 administrative RDP logons for remote access.

Can I just uninstall Terminal Server to revert the RDP functionality back to that of the 2 administrative RDP logons, or is there something else that needs to be done?

What's the best way to uninstall Terminal Services? Through Add/Remove Programs -> Windows Components -> uncheck Terminal Server or through the "Configure Your Server Wizard" by removing the Terminal Server role?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninstalling through Add/Remove Programs [is the officially recommended way of uninstalling Terminal Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779340%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). Once it's removed, you'll only have the regular administrator RDP functionality.

Using the "Configure Your Server Wizard" is just that - the wizardified way of doing what is already pretty point-and-click through Add/Remove Programs.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and the link! I went ahead and removed Terminal Services, and all is well. The only thing I'd like to add is that RDP has to be re-enabled after removing Terminal Services. This can be done by right-clicking My Computer -> Properties -> Remote -> Check "Enable Remote Desktop on this computer".